# Extjs4 - Data store duplicate records. is it possible?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, duplicates, store, records

is it possible to add duplicate records inside data store ?

```
var myData = [
{ id : 0, name : "Rec 0", column1 : "0", column2 : "0" },
{ id : 1, name : "Rec 1", column1 : "1", column2 : "1" },
{ id : 2, name : "Rec 2", column1 : "2", column2 : "2" },
{ id : 3, name : "Rec 3", column1 : "3", column2 : "3" },
{ id : 4, name : "Rec 4", column1 : "4", column2 : "4" },
{ id : 5, name : "Rec 5", column1 : "5", column2 : "5" },
{ id : 6, name : "Rec 6", column1 : "6", column2 : "6" },
{ id : 7, name : "Rec 7", column1 : "7", column2 : "7" },
{ id : 8, name : "Rec 8", column1 : "8", column2 : "8" },
{ id : 9, name : "Rec 9", column1 : "9", column2 : "9" }
];


var origine = new Ext.data.Store({
        //autoDestroy: true,
        storeid: 'origineRec',
        id:'origineRec',
        //model: 'DataObject',
        //idIndex: 0,
        fields: ['id','name','column1 ','column2 '],
        data: myData 
});

var destinazione = new Ext.data.Store({
        //autoDestroy: true,
        storeid: 'destinazioneRec',
        id:'destinazioneRec',
        //idIndex: 0,
        fields: ['id','name','column1 ','column1 ']
});
```

I've a situation like this, two grid panel , two store and i've to drag a record and drop into the "destinazione" and is possibile to allow duplicate records into it.

I add the duplicate records in the second grid (Rec 0 - Rec 0) but after saving into the grid there is only one records.

How can i fix ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default `id` property is primary key and you can't have more then one record in the store with the same key. You can change primary that by specifying `idProperty` to something else, but it's not gonna solve your problem anyway.

If you have two stores and move records from one to another - then it's a good idea to either filter out already selected records from the original store and even remove them.

Comment: i can't delete records from original store. In some cases i need duplicate records.

Comment: If you need duplicated records you need to revise your approach to storing data. Create another `id` field in the destination store.

Comment: Maybe i could solve the problem adding a beforedrop event on the gridpanel and change with new id. i'm trying...